# Please Explain Twitter Bootstrap 3 Grid System

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am not very good with css and am having difficulty understanding Bootstrap 3's grid system.

1. I looked through their source code and it appears as if each col-* class is always 1/12th the width of its parent. But if that were the case, the columns will never stack. But they do. So I must be wrong. Can someone please explain to me how the stacking gets triggered?
2. What is the purpose of the four types of columns - xs, sm, md and lg?

Thank you.

Comment: also read: http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/twitter-bootstrap-3-breakpoints-and-grid/

Comment: Good Read: http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-grid-introduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xs` - Extra small screen sizes
`sm` - Small screen sizes (Mobile)
`md` - Medium sized Screen (Tablet's etc)
`lg` - Large sized Desktop / Laptop

if there are three `col-md-4` (columns in a medium sized screen) in a row, the (3 columns)structure of the webpage wont change until and unless the browser size goes below the medium sized screen i.e `sm`, `xs`. hope you get this.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand now. If I use lg size columns, then the columns will be 1/12th the size of the .container as long as the screen is more than 1200 px wide. Once it goes below 1200, each column will be 100% wide and thus the columns will stack one below the other.

Comment: nope !, only if you use `col-lg-1` or `col-md-1` or `col-sm-1` or `col-xs-1` it'll be 1/12th of the container. More help [here](http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-grid-introduction)

Comment: Yea, I meant col-lg-1.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

1. Bootstrap 3 is "mobile first", meaning that it is intended to be used on phones primarily, and the divs all stack since that is one of the ways to make a mobile design, it's all vertical.

Having said that, of course it's used for larger devices. So by building things with col-sm-*, you are telling it to transform into a grid from the "sm" width up, which happens to be when the browser is 786px wide. The same for md and lg, it just gets bigger.

So yes, it is 12 columns in the grid. The overall width of the grid gets bigger at the breakpoints, meaning the 12 columns are the same percentages, but wider pixels. This is so you can tweak and change the design for a phone, tablet, desktop, and large desktop.

The column sizes inherit downwards, meaning if you make a  col-sm-6, it is a 6 column at md and lg too, you don't have to set it at all three. But, if you wanted it to be 6 at small, but 5 at medium, you would do col-sm-6 and col-md-5

1. The purpose of 4 sizes is so you can change and optimize the layout for multiple screen widths, if desired. Most of the time, people just want col-sm-*, since that will be mobile on mobile devices, but then the normal grid layout on everything else.

I would read these 2 articles to learn more
http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-grid-introduction
http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

Answer (score -1):

The Bootstrap 3 grid comes in 4 sizes (or "breakpoints"). Tiny (for smartphones .col-xs-), Small (for tablets .col-sm-), Medium (for laptops .col-md-) and Large (for laptops/desktops .col-lg-). The 3 grid sizes enable you to control grid behavior on different devices.

For example,

col-sm-3 is 3 grid columns wide (25%) on a typical small device width (more than 768 pixels)

col-md-3 is 3 grid columns wide (25%) on a typical medium device width (more than 992 pixels)

etc..

The sm, md and lg grids will all "stack" vertically on screens/viewports less than 768 pixels. This is where the xs grid fits in. Columns that use the **col-xs-* classes will not stack vertically** and continue to scale down on the smallest screens.

Resize your browser using this [**demo**](http://www.bootply.com/74886) and you'll see the grid scaling effects.

Also, I wrote a more in depth article about [how the Bootstrap grid works](http://blog.codeply.com/2016/04/06/how-the-bootstrap-grid-really-works/).

Read about the [Bootstrap 4 grid system](https://uxplanet.org/how-the-bootstrap-4-grid-works-a1b04703a3b7)